# Refresh page if websocket not received for some time

Tags: javascript, jquery, websocket, page-refresh

I have a page that upon receiving a `websocket`, it does something via `javascript`. I want this page to reload after some time only if a `websocket` wasn't received between the last time and the time I want to.

```
<script>
        if ("WebSocket" in window) {

            var ws = new WebSocket('ws://192.168.33.1:5000');
            var variableSpan = document.getElementById('variable');

            ws.onmessage = function (event) {
                var message = JSON.parse(event.data);
                console.log(message);
                jQuery('#variable').empty();

                $(function () {
                    $.get(message.variable, function (data) {
                        $("#variable").append(data);
                    });
                });

                setTimeout(function () {
                    window.location.reload(); // you can pass true to reload function to ignore the client cache and reload from the server
                }, 10000);
            }
        }
</script>
```

I tried something like this, but it doesn't seem to work. I would appreciate some help :)

Comment: check `if(ws.readyState === WebSocket.CLOSED)` before ` window.location.reload()`

Comment: You will need to clear the previous timeout every time a message is received.

Comment: Also, if you're doing this because of websocket connection problems, you can simply create a new websocket instead of refreshing the page.

Comment: I don't need this for connection errors. In this scenario, it's just a case of the user being "not active"

Answer (score 1):

Reload after checking webSocket State

```
function onWebSocketClosed(){

    if (webSocket.readyState != WebSocket.OPEN) {
        try{
            console.error("webSocket is not open: " + webSocket.readyState +"Reloading Page");
            window.location.reload()
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log('onWebSocketClosed :  {0}' , error)
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: You are suggesting that I should put this code inside the `setTimeout` ?

Comment: I think the best to call the function in the setTimeout